# making a 2x2 plot layout with plots from different platforms

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, layout, heatmap

I am trying to make a 2x2 layout of four plots. I have two plots from ggplot(i.e., ggbiplot) and two plots from heatmap2. My dream was to put them all together in one page. I have followed Claus Wilkes cowplot tutorials. They work fine with ggplot-style plots and base plots (i.e., plots make with the plot command). However, moving to heatmap2 making the desired layout does not result in any 2x2 plot, only single plots.
Appreciate suggestions.
Thanks,
jahn

Comment: Have a look at the patchwork package. It has great vignettes on how to arrange plots (both from ggplot and base). Not sure how exactly the heatmap2 plots will fare in there, but I think it is worth a shot. And it is simple to use. https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that did not do it.